# htaccess force https not working if there is not an URI

Tags: htaccess, apache2

I've never worked with Apache, so I'm a completely newbie.

I have a multihosting account on a provider website, where 3 domain are used.
I want to force https connection on a domain, let's say `example.com`, which is not the main domain of the hosting plan.
What I did is to add an `.htaccess` file in the path `examplecom/public_html`, the folder where there are all  the file of the website. In the `.htaccess` I have copy-pasted this strings from the provider guide:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The website works correctly if I go to a page with an non-empty URI, but it doesn't on the main page.
In example: `http://example.com/anypage` is correctly redirected to `https://www.example.com/anypage`,
while `http://example.com/` is redirected to `https://www.example.com/public_html`, and can't understand why.

Comment: Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file? Is `examplecom/public_html` the document root of this domain? How is this additional domain configured? Where does this point to in relation to the main domain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you might have a conflict with existing directives, however, you can try changing your existing directives to see if it makes a difference:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Providing the `.htaccess` file is located in the `examplecom/public_html` directory then the captured backreference (`$1`) should only contain anything that comes after this (if anything). Whereas the `REQUEST_URI` server variable always contains the full URL-path.

The `RewriteBase` directive is superfluous here since you are using an absolute URL in the `RewriteRule` *substitution*.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing as the erroneous 301 will likely have been cached. Test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid caching issues.

Comment: The solution you suggest worked perfectly! Thanks